# R function setseed() doesn't work in external R script on SQL Server 2017 with function kmeans()

Tags: sql, r, machine-learning, sql-server-2017

I use the setseed () function in RStudio to re-generate the same random output. Specifically, the clustering search function "k-means clustering." In RStudio and in the R language console it works.
However, when I enter the same command to an external script in SSMS, I always generate different numbers (specifically the code work succesfully, but every run is ended with different result, what I dont want).

T-SQL external script is:

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language =N'R', @script=N'
library("plyr")
library("FactoMineR")
library("factoextra")
library("corrplot")
library("dplyr")
library("cluster")
library("ggplot2")
library("magrittr")

str(InputDataSet)
costs <- as.data.frame(InputDataSet)

costs.active <- costs[,c(3, 5, 6, 7)] 

set.seed(123)
km.res <- kmeans(costs.active, 10, nstart = 25)
dd <- cbind(costs
        , cluster = km.res$cluster)
d <- ddply(dd, .(cluster), nrow)

OutputDataSet <- as.data.frame(d);' @input_data_1 = '...'
```

The following is already a classic SQL source code.

EDIT
Now I found that, for example, the rnorm () function works fine. Is it possible that it would be related to kmeans function?

Can anyone helps me please?

Comment: Can you simplify the function to only use `set.seed` and return the result of say `runif(10)`? That way you could verify your suspicion that `set.seed` is not working.

Comment: @RalfStubner I edit my question now. I try to use function rnorm() with set.seed(123) and it works good. But in case with kmeans it doesnt work.